# Are the SNP frontbenchers in the UK Parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, house-of-commons

As we know, there is a government frontbench with ministers that is mirrored by the respective ministers of the opposition and the shadow ministers.

What about the SNP though? They clearly occupy the front bench of parliament but are they considered frontbenchers or backbenchers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontbench_Team_of_Ian_Blackford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently the seating was controversial.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-32802374)

The shadow minister positions don't have a formal definition but exist by convention. The frontbench/backbench system matters a lot more for the government, where ministers are expected to observe "cabinet collective responsibility" and stick closely to the Party line. Although this has broken down since 2017 and the current emergency.

To me it seems reasonable to classify them as "frontbench".